# Convert Javascript array to python list?

Tags: python

I want to make google trasnlate script.
I am making a request to translate.google.com and google return an array  but the array contains undefined items.You can imagine response comes as string.
I can remove commas if there is more than one consecutive with regex etc. but I am looking best solution :)

How can I convert this javascript array to python list?

```
["a","b",,,"e"]
```

My script : http://ideone.com/jhjZe

Comment: @Marcin that won't work. this isn't valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/), so the parser will reject it.

Comment: @mata Right, but if he has a real javascript array, he can just stop creating this string which isn't syntactically valid in either language.

Comment: @Marcin: His `["a","b",,,"e"]` is equal to `["a", "b", undefined, undefined, "e"]` in JavaScript. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gtehr/. Maybe it differs across browsers, but this is what I get in Chrome.

Comment: @Tadeck So, I don't see the problem. He can still convert it to json as per your answer.

Answer (score 24):

### JavaScript part - encoding

In Javascript you do:

```js
var arr = ["a","b",,,"e"];
var json_string = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

then you somehow pass `json_string` (now equal to "`["a","b",null,null,"e"]`" string) from JavaScript to Python.

### Python part - decoding

Then, on Python side do:

```py
json_string = '["a","b",null,null,"e"]'  # passed from JavaScript

try:
    import simplejson as json
except (ImportError,):
    import json

result = json.loads(json_string)
```

As a result you get `[u'a', u'b', None, None, u'e']` in Python.

### More links

See below:

- [demo of JavaScript part](http://jsfiddle.net/Gtehr/),
- [Documentation on JSON.stringify() at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify),
- [demo of Python part](http://ideone.com/oqnQZ),

### Dependencies

The above solutions require:

- `JSON.stringify()` in JavaScript, which is in all mobile browsers, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and in IE since version 8.0 (more detailed list of compatible browsers is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Browser_compatibility)),
- `json` Python library (the above code will use `simplejson` optionally, if available, but is not required), which comes in standard library,

So, in short **there are no external dependencies**.

Comment: I cant use JSON.stringify because JSON.stringify a javascript function .I cant use it .So there is no null.There is commas consecutively.

Comment: @mesuutt: So you say you do not have access to JavaScript and you want to parse JavaScript variable from Python?

Comment: Yes I want to parse javascript array from python.You can look my script : [http://ideone.com/jhjZe](http://ideone.com/jhjZe)

Comment: @mesuutt: Try [`python-spidermonkey`](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/) then for example. The following may work for you: `from spidermonkey import Runtime; rt = Runtime(); cx = rt.new_context(); result = cx.eval_script('["a","b",,,"e"]')`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I am getting that spidermonkey.Context object has no attribute 'eval_script' error.There is another method instead of using library?

Comment: What's the purpose of ImportError in a tuple?

Comment: What?.I do not understand you @pdknsk

Comment: @pdknsk: This is redundant, but I consider it a good practice - when adding another exception to be caught by the same clause you will do it in a more readable way, avoiding issues described here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-python3-2/#exceptions

Comment: @mesuutt: I was mostly quoting their tutorial (http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/). Yes, there are other methods, but using JavaScript parsing library (you are not limited to SpiderMonkey) is the most reliable method. Other methods would be just mostly walkarounds and hacks.

Comment: Ok.I thought solution of the problem is easy and I thought I can solve without using any additional library.I am solving with `re.sub("[,]{2,}","",str)` for now because script should run without any dependency(except basic libraries).Thanks

Comment: @mesuutt: This is your choice, but if you need some reliability, try to find better regular expression for splitting. Consider eg. `["a,,b","b",,,"e"]`. Although this may work for you, if you are sure about the kind of values you receive.

Comment: I wrote code wrong.This work without any problem on any string : `re.sub("[,]{2,}",",",str)` :)

Comment: @mesuutt: I have added more details on the fact that _there are no external dependencies_. If you disagree, please let me know.

Comment: does not work json.loads only get first elemnt from list and